# Align base line of textviews in two different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, textview

I want to align baselines of tow `TextViews` placed in two different `RelativeLayouts`. Following is the code I am using:

```
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tv_city_a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="City"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

         <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

             <TextView 
                 android:id="@+id/tv_city_b"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tv_city"
                 android:background="@drawable/txt_field_white"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to align the baseline of `tv_city_a` with `tv_city_b` but the above code is not working.

**Note:** Due to design requirements, I need to place the `TextView`'s in two different `RelativeLayout`'s. I can not put them in one.

**Edit** Following is the output I am getting:
[image]

Comment: can you post your output or your complete layout

Comment: you can place both relative layout in some linear layout

Answer (score 0):

You can't link the baseline for views with different parents. Your only options is to join them in 1 `RelativeLayout` OR make them align by giving correct padding, margin, parent aligning etc. etc.

Edit: The wrong output is comming because you have `android:paddingTop="5dp"` in the second RelativeLayout

Comment: So its not possible to achieve what I am trying to. Is there any other method?

Comment: @VinodMaurya you could try to measure the placement of TextView A and then place TextView B accordingly...